# counting words of a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, count

As the title states, few things I must add to explain: `" "/tab/","/"."` are things that divide words in my situation, another note that there can be more the one space or dot coming one after the other

this is what I have

```
int countWords(char * str, int length){
       int counter = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(( str[i] == " ") || ( str[i] == ".") || ( str[i] == ",")){
                if(( str[i+1] != " ") || ( str[i+1] != ".") || (str[i+1] != ",")){
                    if(( str[i-1] != " ") || ( str[i-1] != ".") || (str[i-1] != ","))
                        counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

I get an error saying that I can not compare int and a pointer, I do understand where that is coming from, but how can I get it to actually work?

Note* I can't use `string.h`

Comment: It's a good thing you can't use `string.h`. But please use the `string` header. :)

Comment: `str[i] == " "` Doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ so it doesn't count for spaces, what else should I do?

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb Use a character literal for comparison instead: `str[i] == ' '`

Comment: I think you can get a good solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Comment: Duplicate of [Warning comparison between pointer and integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510218/warning-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer) or [Reading string by char till end of line C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726724/reading-string-by-char-till-end-of-line-c-c)

Comment: when checking for a word separator, suggest also checking for `'` `;` `?` `:` and similar characters

Comment: These are not actually requested as the input can not contain these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expressions like this

```
str[i] == " "
          ^^^
```

you are trying to compare an object of type `char` with a string literal that is implicitly converted to the type `char *`.

You have to use a character constant instead of the string literal

```
str[i] == ' '
          ^^^
```

The enclosing if statements do not make sense. For example for `i`  equal to 0 the expression `str[i-1]` tries to access memory beyond the string.

The first parameter of the function should be declared with qualifier `const`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t countWords( const char *s ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; )
    {
        while (s[i] == ' '  || 
               s[i] == '\t' || 
               s[i] == '.'  || 
               s[i] == ',') ++i;

        if (s[i] != '\0')
        {
            ++n;
            while ( s[i] != '\0' &&
                    ! ( s[i] == ' '  ||
                        s[i] == '\t' ||
                        s[i] == '.'  ||
                        s[i] == ',')) ++i;

        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "  Hello\t, World...";

    printf("%zu\n", countWords(s));
}
```

The program output is

```
2
```

Or the function's implementation can look like

```
size_t countWords(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        while (*s == ' '  ||
               *s == '\t' ||
               *s == '.'  ||
               *s == ',') ++s;

        if ( *s )
        {
            ++n;
            while ( *s &&
                    !( *s == ' '  ||
                       *s == '\t' ||
                       *s == '.'  ||
                       *s == ',' ) ) ++s;

        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

A more general approach of declaring the function is the following

```
size_t countWords( const char *s1, const char *s2 );
```

where the string `s2`  specifies a set of word separators.

Comment: So ugly, you may consider to use `strsep()` instead.

Comment: @0andriy Ordinarily, I'd agree, but the question notes that no string functions are allowed to be used, whether they're from the standard headers or from implementation-specific headers.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Strange requirement... Though OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count word there is one fine example in K&R ANSI C. Try to write program like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN  1    /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0    /* outside a word */
/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
   int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
   state = OUT;
   nl = nw = nc = 0;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
 {
    ++nc;
    if (c == '\n')
        ++nl;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
        state = OUT;
    else if (state == OUT) 
    {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
     }
   }
printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Hope this helps. :) You can find the pdf of this book [here](http://alvand.basu.ac.ir/~dezfoulian/files/Programming/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20C%20Programming%20Language-%20Brian%20W.%20Kernighan,%20Dennis%20M.%20Ritchie,%202nd%20ed.,%20ISBN%20.pdf).